# Counting number of times words appear In strings

Tags: python

I was practicing from coding bat and the question was to find the number of times the word ‘code’ appears in a string, but the letter ‘d’ in ‘code’ can be substituted for any letter. So “code” has count 1, ‘cope’ also 1. I wrote some code but it doesn't work. I don't understand why it doesn't work. The function returns 0 for every input. Here is a link to what I tried https://codingbat.com/prob/p186048

```
def count_code(str):
     count = 0
     str = str.lower()
     for x in str:
         if x == ‘c’ and str.find(x) + 1 == “o” and str.find(x) + 3 == “e”:
            count += 1
     return count
```

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  The code you posted merely defines a function and quits without executing anything.  "It doesn't work" is not a problem specification -- write your test cases and *show* us the problem.

Answer (score 3):

As Tim mentioned I would go for regular expressions in such tasks however, if you need a simpler way(not the most efficient but one way to do it):

```
import string


text = 'elephant code joke cole coke man'
total = 0
for letter in string.ascii_lowercase:
    total += text.count(f'co{letter}e')
print(f'{total}')
```

Note that in your solution attempt, there is this:

```
for x in str:
```

Apart from the fact that you should avoid name collisions `str` in that case, for a text of size 1000 characters, you'll be doing 1000 iterations, reduced to 26 iterations(letters of the alphabet) using this approach.

Comment: What does the f do?

Comment: This is an f-string (python 3.6 +)  check this https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/

Answer (score 1):

I would use `re.findall` here, and then just take the count of how many matches were found:

```
inp = "blah code blah cole blah core blah"
print(len(re.findall(r'\bco[a-z]e\b', inp)))    # prints 3
```

The regex pattern used here is `\bco[a-z]e\b`, which matches any word `code`, where the third letter `d` can actually be any letter.

Comment: and for any character, not just letters: print(len(re.findall(r'\bco.?e\b', inp)))

Comment: @DavidErickson No, that regex pattern isn't right.  There should be no `?` after the third letter dot, otherwise it would also match things like `coe`

Comment: could you please provide a more beginner friendly solution . I don’t understand any of these.

Comment: Do you need to import anything to use re.findall ? Coding bat says ‘re’ is undefined

Comment: Yes, use: `import re`

Comment: Hello Tim. I was wondering whether it is possible to do it without using import.

Comment: @BumBum No, if you want to use the `re` functions, then you will have to import that library -- somewhere.

Comment: Can you do it without using the re function ? Like something that does not import anything?

Answer (score 0):

You've confused the index and the contents of the characters:

```
str.find(x) + 1 == ‘o’
```

This can *never* be true: your `find` call will return the *position* of the first such character in the string.  You add 1 to that index.  How do you imagine that this integer sum can be equal to the character 'o'?  An integer and a character cannot be equal.

You need to back up and redesign your logic.  When you do that, see this lovely reference for [debugging help](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs).  You need to learn how to trace problems in your own code.

Comment: Ohhhh. Wait so if I set it equal to the index of ‘o’ and ‘e’ will it work?

Comment: You should *know* whether or not it will work before writing here -- you *try* it.  Don't ask *us* -- ask the Python interpreter in front of you.

Comment: ok I set it to the index of ‘o’ and ‘e’ and coding bat says it works for more than half of the tests. However , if there is an input like ‘xxcozeyycop’ the program returns 2 whereas the expected answer is 1.

Comment: ... which is due to misuse of `find`.  What did your debugging tell you about the internal operation?  This is not a discussion appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression for this, It's fast, convenient and short code.

```
#CODE
import re

#findall() Returns a list containing all matches
str="cole code cope"
result = re.findall("co.e", str) 
print(len(result))
#END
```

Hope this will fulfill your requirement.

Comment: This is (almost) a verbatim copy of my answer, which I posted 2 hours earlier.  This isn't how the site works.